# .ipa installation through OTA

Tags: ios

I downloaded an.ipa of "xyz" app from iTunes say HSBC.ipa(I do not own this application).
Can I install this application on the device through OTA or the applications downloaded from iTunes have to be installed via iTunes itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the code signing of the ipa. If it is signed for adhoc deployment (or for enterprise), and your device is included, you will be able to install it. However, if it was signed for the App Store you will not be able to install it via OTA.